# Atempting to style a pseudo nested list in XSL-FO

Tags: xsl-fo

I'm really starting to love XSL-FO and am sort of starting to begin to maybe get where I want to be in terms of styling these documents but I'm having a bit of a brain freeze with trying to emulate lists.

The XML I have to work with doesn't use DITA lists and we have had to fudge it to get it into XPP and then out to the web and now into SDL's LiveContent.

This is the markup I have for a list:

```
<p outputclass="LC NText"><b>[12]</b>&#x00A0;&#x00A0;&#x00A0;On 24&#x00A0;October 2006, following a second CMC on 23&#x00A0;October 2006, XXXXXX, by this stage legally represented, made its application for disclosure. The application requests disclosure of the following documents:</p> 
<p outputclass="LC"><ph outputclass="NList1_num">(a)</ph><ph outputclass="NList1_text">the minute of the case review meeting;</ph></p> 
<p outputclass="LC"><ph outputclass="NList1_num">(b)</ph><ph outputclass="NList1_text">Mr&#x00A0;Mayock&#x2019;s memorandum regarding his review of the case;</ph></p> 
<p outputclass="LC"><ph outputclass="NList1_num">(c)</ph><ph outputclass="NList1_text">Mr&#x00A0;Priddis&#x2019; memorandum;</ph></p> 
<p outputclass="LC"><ph outputclass="NList1_num">(d)</ph><ph outputclass="NList1_text">the final draft of the case closure letter to be sent by Mr&#x00A0;Mayock;</ph></p> 
<p outputclass="LC"><ph outputclass="NList1_num">(e)</ph><ph outputclass="NList1_text">the draft summary of final comments from interested parties received in connection with the OFT&#x2019;s provisional decision to close its investigations.</ph></p>
```

I am needing to indent the outputclass="NList1_num" and outputclass="NList1_text" by a specific amount (we also have NList*_ where * is 2,3,4 etc for further indented nested lists).

I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(@outputclass,'NList1_')]">
        <fo:block text-indent="2em">
        <fo:inline background-color="red">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </fo:inline>
        </fo:block>
    </xsl:template>
```

but this displays it with the NList1_num indented on one line and the NList1_text with the same indent on the next line. I'm wanting them both on the same line as per a normal list.

I tried fo:inline but found that I couldn't apply an indent or margin to these and had to use fo:block instead.

Can someone please give me some ideas how to get these styled.

Many thanks (again).

Hedley Phillips

Comment: You should be matching the outer `p` as list item.

Answer (score 1):

Suggested approach:

1. Create a small document, *by hand*, that contains the XSL-FO markup that you need. Make use of the [available list constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#d0e12374):

   - fo:list-block
   - fo:list-item
   - fo:list-item-body
   - fo:list-item-label
2. When you have something that works, start developing the stylesheet that produces the wanted markup.

Comment: Thanks for your comments but I am still getting absolutely nowhere with this. The closest I can get is if I place the _num and _text into fo:block's but I can't get them both on one line. The second block always drops the next line down. Is it possible to set a block width and float them left as in css?

Comment: Typical, seconds after posting I think I have it. I am using margin-top="-12pt" on the _text to shift it up so that it is inline with the _num

Comment: @Hedley: OK, if it works, that's great. But I do maintain that it's odd to "emulate" lists with fo:block instead of using the proper formatting objects that are available.

Comment: @mzjn I agree. But we have such a convoluted system here. Files come in styled in Word, these are then converted to RTF if they are .docs, then XML via Omnimark and one of many DTD's , then into XPP then out of XPP still as XML then back to Word and sent back to the customer. The other branch is the XML that came out of XPP is converted into DITA XML, imported into Livecontent, styled via CSS for the browser display and then styled via XSL-FO for the pdf print display. Now. The lists we have aren't numbered or sequential. They might go a,b,c,d 1,s, 9, Jones, 1,g,3 etc and that is just 1 list!

Comment: @Hedley: Yes, your system seems convoluted indeed. But I honestly can't see how "faking it" makes the system any less convoluted (or less fragile). Using `fo:list-block`, `fo:list-item` etc. is not extremely hard. Non-sequential lists should not be a problem.

Comment: @mzjn, I agree, but unfortunately at the time we had a very short, customer led window before these books went to press and I think the consensus was to fudge it and just get them out on time. Yes, I have berated the guy who did this... ;-)

Comment: @Hedley: Since you seem to agree with most of what I say, I think I deserve at least an upvote... :-).